# How to display categories menu to other block?

Tags: magento, categories

I am using magento 1.7 and i want to change the position of my categories menu to other place.
Now categories are displayed in my header but i want them in the content.

So this is the code in my header that is displaying the categories:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0, 'level-top', 'sub-wrapper' ) ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<nav class="queldorei">
    <ul id="queldoreiNav">
        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('shoppersettings/navigation/home')): ?>
         <li class="level0 level-top">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span></a>
         </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        echo $_menu;
?>
</nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

If i copy this code and place it in the content it gives me an error:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 796667554198
```

Do you know why this is happening and how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml (or with you own path) you must have some lines that tells magento to add that menu to your header, this lines:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

so, remove that lines and add to the content block, in the same file down there. It should be like this:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```